# CSV File read in Python 3 and Django

Tags: python, string, file, csv

I'm writing a Webapp with Django and im trying to open a csv file.

On my local machine that was no problem (there I used python2.7 or something).

On the Server, Python 3 is installed and I get an Error:

```
'_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'xreadlines'
```

But i didnt use this `xreadlines`...

```
    with open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../***.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        for row in readCSV: 
             #...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how did u initialize the csv reader

Comment: I believe you missed some lines here, where is this `xreadlines` coming from?

Comment: The Problem was that i didnt reload the Apache Server after updating the Code... Problem solved now ;)